# string formatting for SQL query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I shoot a query via python like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblMQTTtest (string) VALUES ('test')")
con.commit()
```

which works fine. But if I come to the point and I will use a spaceholder, I get an error message :/

```
var1 = 'mystring'
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblMQTTtest (string) VALUES (%s)", (var1))
con.commit()
```

Error:

> ```
> File "mqtt1.py", line 25, in write
> cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblMQTTtest (string) VALUES (%s)", (var1))
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `(var1)` isn't a tuple. It's just a variable in parentheses. Should be `(var1,)`

Comment: I didn't expected that I have to use a tuple for a single value. It works and it was driving me crazy. Thank you!

Comment: While reading again the duplicate I can confirm it would have answered my question if I had read it with the background of knowing the tuple.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to replace the comma with %. Python doesn’t know how to fill in `%s` without an `%` operator. Try:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblMQTTtest (string) VALUES (%s)" % var1 )
```

Comment: This is bad advice. You shouldn't glue variables into your SQL. The OP had it right, passing the variables separately to `execute`. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Can you explain why this is bad advice?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/327/